# Extracting maximum number from DataFrame of strings (and some NaN values)

Tags: python, pandas, regex

Look at the DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data=pd.DataFrame(['random 15 numbers 128 and 12 letters','12-5','page 65'],columns=['text'])
```

[image]

I want to extract all numbers from the strings and write the maximum number into a new column. I achieved that with this code:

```
data['list']=data['text'].str.extractall('(\d+)').unstack().values.tolist()
data['max']=data['list'].apply(lambda row:max([int(x) for x in row if x is not np.nan]))
```

This results in this DataFrame:

[image]

First question: Is there a more elegant way to do that?

My actual problem: My code works only if there is no `NaN` value in my original DataFrame. How would you adapt the code in that case? The result should be a `NaN` column for each `NaN` value with the correct index. Replace the `data` defining line by the following to make the problem appear:

```
data=pd.DataFrame(['random 15 numbers 128 and 12 letters','12-5','page 65',np.nan],columns=['text'])
```

Additionally I want to deal the code with entrys which are not `NaN` but strings without a number. In that case the intermediate list should be empty and the last row should be `NaN` (this last thing is easy to achive by manipulating the last line).

Comment: If your code works and you seek enhancement only, consider posting the question at [codereview.se].

Comment: Please provide sample data (as text) which demonstrates what you want to achieve with your "actual problem" and the "additional" question

Comment: @Nick I thought it would be easy for everybody who is able to solve the problem to add `NaN` or 'any string' to the DataFrame. But I just edited the question to do so.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My main point was not the code but the problem with `NaN` values. But I already expected that it occurs because of my bad code and that there is a more elegant way. @mozway proved that I was right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a list as intermediate, directly go with a [`groupby.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.max.html):

```
data['max'] = (data['text']
              .str.extractall('(\d+)')[0]
              .astype(int)
              .groupby(level=0).max()
              )
```

Output:

```
                                   text    max
0  random 15 numbers 128 and 12 letters  128.0
1                                  12-5   12.0
2                               page 65   65.0
3                                   NaN    NaN
```

If you need both the list and the max:

```
g = (data['text']
     .str.extractall('(\d+)')[0]
     .astype(int)
     .groupby(level=0)
     )

data['list'] = g.agg(list)
data['max'] = g.max()
```

Output:

```
                                   text           list    max
0  random 15 numbers 128 and 12 letters  [15, 128, 12]  128.0
1                                  12-5        [12, 5]   12.0
2                               page 65           [65]   65.0
3                                   NaN            NaN    NaN
```